# Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. Even if installed mod_ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl, sslengine

I want to Enable SSL on apache server. i made proper configuration in **httpd.conf** as well as **httpd-ssl.conf** .
But When i am starting apache Server following error is comming :
** Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration **.

Note :- I have installed mod_ssl through yum using root user.Right now i am logged in non root user and starting apche server which results to above error.

Comment: does "httpd -L " output show this directive ?

Comment: Yes.. It gives output as follow :
[weblogic@mum00cdd ~]$ httpd -L
<Directory (core.c)
        Container for directives affecting resources located in the specified directories
        Allowed in *.conf only outside <Directory>, <Files> or